# Set a variable as default in HTML select option through python

Tags: jinja2

I have a python flask code that opens the html page with select options & radio buttons. In the html POST method python reads the user inputs using 'request.form[]' and connects to Netezza tabase and using SQL fetches the result. But I am unable to get the result reflected on the same html page **by preserving user selections.** I am rendering the same html page again so that the result table gets refreshed on the same page; but for obvious reasons dropdowns & radio buttons will be reset.

Is there a way to set a variable as default selected value in html template (the variable would be the option that user selects during the GET method) without using php?

Also any other way by which I can get my results displayed on the same page by preserving user selections would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Here is my Python code:**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def open_html():

  if request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template('SelectionPage.html')

  elif request.method == 'POST':
      my_duration = request.form['colorRadio']
      my_region = request.form['regiom_select']
      my_sport = request.form['sport_select']

      ##Here it connects to database and fetches the result using sql

      rows=c.fetchall() 
      print(rows[0], '', rows[-1]) 

      ##Need help here
      return render_template('SelectionPage.html', rows=rows) 

      connection.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import os
      HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
  try:
      PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
  except ValueError:
      PORT = 5555
  app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

**Here is my html (SelectionPage.html)**

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <div>               
                <div>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="Current Month">Current Month</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="Last Month">Last Month</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="Current Quarter">Current Quarter</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="YTD">YTD</label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Select Region</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="region_select" class="span4">
                            <option value="WW">WW</option>
                            <option value="NA">NA</option>
                            <option value="AP">AP</option>
                            <option value="ANZ">ANZ</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td><span>Brand Sport</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="sport_select" class="span4">
                            <option value="SOCCER">SOCCER</option>
                            <option value="HOCKEY">HOCKEY</option>
                            <option value="VOLLEYBALL">VOLLEYBALL</option>
                            <option value="CRICKET">CRICKET</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>     
            <br />
            <br />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>                
</form> 
<div>
            <h4>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </h4>

            {% for row in rows %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}                 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can anyone pls help me with a solution for my query above? thank you.